# Brace highlighting Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Brace highlighting works with the default color scheme in VS 2008.  I downloaded and I'm currently using the VibrantInk theme and the braces aren't highlighting.  I've gone through the options even changed the ones that said brace highlighting and nothing.  Any ideas as to whats going on?

Also, when I am typing out strings and I put the last quote, the text goes completely black (against a black background) until I space or perform some other action then it goes to being green.  This is mildly annoying.  Any clues as to what's going on here?

Comment: I recall that I needed to restart VS in order to get some themes to work properly, have you done that already?

Comment: there are two, can't remember which one is which. but play around with both in the VS color settings (brace highlight and something else)

Comment: it's the brace matching one. all you can set it the background. also, brace highlighting only works on outside of braces.

Comment: Have you fixed this? I have tried to try to change Brace Matching (Rectangle): Item Background to black background, but it doesn't solve the problem. I am also curious about how to try to change that "Automatic" thing because it's disabled right now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a Vibrant Ink derivative and brace matching works for me. In the Fonts and Colors option, I have "Brace Matching (Rectangle): Item Background" set to the color I want to highlight the braces with.

To fix the second issue, go to Tools | Options | Fonts and Colors and then just hit save. At least, that fixes it for me. It's very annoying however to have to do this and the bug shows up again seemingly randomly. (Edit: I just realized that many of the colors were set to "Automatic". I've explicitly set them to a color now in hopes that this will solve the disappearing text issue.)

I've experienced a few issues with certain settings not being saved no matter how many times I set them (particularly auto inserting quotes in HTML attributes which I turn on, but never sticks). This happens on multiple machines too. I think VS2008 just has some bugs for persisting some settings. Haven't checked Connect on this yet though.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the brace matching rectangle option and that fixed it.  The issue with the strings changing color to something I couldn't see also "magically" went away.  We're all peachy now.

Comment: The disappearing strings will be back, I promise you (it shows up for me about once a day)

Answer (score 1):

Check the Tools | Options | Text Editor | General | Automatic Delimiter highlighting setting to make sure it is on.

Comment: Thanks, that setting was set properly though.